# Getting Information on active Restore in TSQL / SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On my server a database is currently restoring according to the SQL Server Management Studio

In the history

```
SELECT *
FROM MSDB..RestoreHistory WITH (nolock)
WHERE destination_database_name = 'myDB'
ORDER BY restore_date DESC
```

I can't see any entry of that restore currently running.

Is there any other system-table where I can find out who started the restore and when?

Comment: What makes you think that the database is currently in the middle of a restore?  I'm guessing you're just looking at Object Explorer (SSMS) and seeing the text "Restoring..." right next to your database?  Is that correct?

Comment: I am looking in SQL Management Studio. It sais "Restoring" and accessing the database (via sql management studio or code) fails because of restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the restore progress, use below t-sql

```
SELECT command,
            s.text,
            start_time,
            percent_complete, 
            CAST(((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate()))/3600) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
                  + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%3600)/60 as varchar) + 'min, '
                  + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar) + ' sec' as running_time,
            CAST((estimated_completion_time/3600000) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
                  + CAST((estimated_completion_time %3600000)/60000 as varchar) + 'min, '
                  + CAST((estimated_completion_time %60000)/1000 as varchar) + ' sec' as est_time_to_go,
            dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as est_completion_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
WHERE r.command in ('RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE', 'RESTORE LOG', 'BACKUP LOG')
```

> Is there any other system-table where I can find out who started the restore and when?

You can find out the restore history - especially the user_name will give you who restored the database.

```
SELECT  [rs].[destination_database_name], 
[rs].[restore_date], 
[bs].[backup_start_date], 
[bs].[user_name],
[bs].[backup_finish_date], 
[bs].[database_name] as [source_database_name], 
[bmf].[physical_device_name] as [backup_file_used_for_restore]
FROM msdb..restorehistory rs
INNER JOIN msdb..backupset bs
ON [rs].[backup_set_id] = [bs].[backup_set_id]
INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily bmf 
ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf].[media_set_id] 
--where [rs].[destination_database_name] like '%database_name%' -- OPTIONAL FILTER
ORDER BY [rs].[restore_date] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one looks nice. To the second part: I already selected rows of the restorehistory (as mentionend in the question). It looks like ACTIVE restores are just not in there

Comment: The first one gives you active restores and second one gives you restore history.